# Unrecognized field class not marked as ignorable

Tags: java, json, rest, jboss, resteasy

Having the following:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <display-name>avdisws</display-name>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
            <param-value>paqA.paqB.paqC.RestApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>       
    </servlet>

</web-app>
```

**Class Book.java:**

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"title", "author", "price"})
public class Book {

    private String title; 
    private String author; 
    private Double price;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

**Class BookService.java:**

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("bookService")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + "; charset=ISO-8859-15")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class BookService {

    @POST
    @Path("test")
    public Book getBook(@Context HttpServletRequest request, Book book) {

        Book returnedBook = new Book();
            returnedBook.setAuthor("Test Author");
            returnedBook.setTitle("Test Title");
            returnedBook.setPrice(99.99);

        return returnedBook;
    }

}
```

**Class RestApplication:**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public RestApplication() {
        super();
        singletons.add(new BookService());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }

}
```

In my local **JBoss AS 6** environment, I'am able to call http://localhost:8080/avdisws/bookService/test properly with this JSON:

```
{
    "book":
    {
        "title": "Some book",
        "author": "Some author",
        "price": 89.21
    }
}
```

BUT in the DESA environment, with **Jboss EAP 7.1** I get:

*Unrecognized field "book" (class paqA.paqB.paqC.Book), not marked as ignorable*

If I do the call with next JSON it doesnt fails:

```
{
        "title": "Some book",
        "author": "Some author",
        "price": 89.21
    }
```

These are the libraries I am using:

```
javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
jaxrs-api-3.0.10.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxrs-3.0.10.Final.jar
resteasy-client-3.0.10.Final.jar
resteasy-jaxb-provider-3.0.10.Final.jar
resteasy-jettison-provider-3.0.10.Final.jar
httpclient-4.5.3.jar
httpcore-4.4.6.jar
commons-io-2.6.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar
jettison-1.3.8.jar
```

Using **@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)** does not solve the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, this solve the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```